# Using $(I - T)^{-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{}T^n$ in the solution of another problem.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, operator-theory

Can I use this problem:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T \in \mathcal{L}(X, X)$ with $\|T\| < 1.$ Define $T^0 = I.$
(a) Use the completeness of $\mathcal{L}(X, X)$ to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} T^n$ converges in $\mathcal{L}(X, X).$
(b) Show that $(I - T)^{-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{}T^n.$

To prove this one

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T,S \in \mathcal{L(X)}.$ Suppose that $T$ is invertible and that $\|T-S\| < \|T^{-1}\|^{-1}.$ Prove that $S$ is invertible.

If so, How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|I-T^{-1}S\|=\|T^{-1}T-T^{-1}S\| \leq \|T^{-1}\|\|T-S\|<1$ so $T^{-1}S$ is invertible by the result you have quoted. This implies that $S=T(T^{-1}S)$ is also invertible.

Comment: So we need not use the question I mentioned?

Comment: Why the first part of your first sentence leads you to say that "so $T^{-1}S$ is invertible" I can not see this .... could you clarify please?

Comment: but why convergence means invertible? as 0 operator is convergent but it is not invertible.

Comment: @Secretly You are allowed to use the fact that $\|U\|<1$ implies $I-U$ is invertible (and its inverse is given by a certain series). Take $U=I-T^{-1}S$.